# Which minified processing js should I use for runtime

Tags: processing.js

http://processingjs.org/content/download/processing-js-1.2.1/processing-1.2.1.min.js
http://processingjs.org/content/download/processing-js-1.2.1/processing-1.2.1-api.min.js

Just observed that 2 javascript files are shipped in the distribution, what should I use for runtime functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either one, however the minified version is optimized for production because it saves bandwidth. If you plan on just using canned functionality from the script, the http://processingjs.org/content/download/processing-js-1.2.1/processing-1.2.1.min.js will do fine. However, if you wish to have the ability to change the code in the future, the api is what you want.

- Jeffrey Kevin Pry

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the non -api version.  Looks like they [added a seperate build](https://processing-js.lighthouseapp.com/projects/41284/tickets/1096-create-an-api-only-version-of-processingjs) which only includes the js API itself -- it doesn't include the parser which translates from processing into js.